# pattern for reading particular stack trace from log file in java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am reading a log file using `BufferedReader` and I want to extract a particular stack trace from the log file. However, I cannot read it, the output is empty.

for example I have an exception for the word: client
and the stack trace for it is like:

> java.sql.SQLException: Unknown column 'client' in 'field list'
>
> SELECT query
>
> at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2928) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1571) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1666) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2994) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:936)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1030)
>   at telemed.admin.DAO.AdminDAO.getTeleVisitorData(AdminDAO.java:87) at
>   telemed.admin.AdminService.getTeleVisitors(AdminService.java:31) at
>   org.apache.jsp.jsp.telemed.telemedResponse_jsp._jspService(telemedResponse_jsp.java:330)
>   at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)

I am trying to read the stack trace which has a particular word in that but not in Exception Line.

my code is:

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:/exp.txt"));
String temp;
Pattern expPattern=Pattern.compile("(?s).*Exception:.*client.*[\\n\\r].*");

while((temp=br.readLine())!=null){
    //System.out.println("line::::"+temp);
    Matcher headlineMatcher=expPattern.matcher(temp);
    if(headlineMatcher.find()){
        System.out.println("=>"+temp);
        temp=null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line do you need to extact?

Comment: this whole exception stack trace.it contains "client"

Comment: Regex buddy is showing your pattern as a match. I'd have to guess that it's regarding the java code specifically in how you're handling the pattern's results, maybe not the pattern itself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that `readLine()` returns a line **without** any lineend characters. So you cannot match them.

One possible solution is to match the first line and print a fixed number of following lines or until you find a line which can be identified as the last line of your interest.

Take the snippet as simple demonstration.

```
Pattern expPattern = Pattern.compile("(?s).*Exception:.*client.*");
int followingLines = 4;

try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("exp.txt"), UTF_8)) {
    for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
        if (expPattern.matcher(line).find()) {
            System.out.println("=>" + line);
            for (int i = 0; i < followingLines; i++) {
                line = br.readLine();
                if (line == null) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("=>" + line);
            }
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

The output is.

```
=>java.sql.SQLException: Unknown column 'client' in 'field list'
=>
=>SELECT query
=>
=>at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2928) at ...
```

Comment: thanks for your response! ,here lineend is last occurence of this  bracket  :   ')' before any new exception stack trace.

Comment: @ParmarKamlesh I was not sure, as I copy and paste your output, which did not contain a linebreak at this position. But I guess it should be anyway clear what I wanted to show with the short snippet.